# ANR occurs randomly

Tags: android, firebase, multithreading, android-camera, anr

My ENV

- Android 11
- SoC rk3588 (custom SBC)
- avaliable storage 25GB
- ram 4GB

My Project Features

- Firebase (analytics, storage)
- Lottie (animation)
- Tflite
- Camera2 + CameraX
  (I use two camera devices at the same time & both camera is external module)
- SerialModules (NFC Card reader, QR Code Reader, LED)

Everythings is work fine almost during 10min (error occured randomly)

I checked Firebase crashlytics

- ANR android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Unknown root cause)
- ANR android.os.MessageQueue.next (Unknown root cause)

Error Message

```
2023-11-01 15:49:42.025  9559-9569  e.myproj.dem          com.myProject          I  Background concurrent copying GC freed 65016(2687KB) AllocSpace objects, 169(26MB) LOS objects, 40% free, 35MB/59MB, paused 68us,58us total 321.978ms
2023-11-01 15:49:42.986  9559-9569  e.myproj.dem          com.myProject          I  Background young concurrent copying GC freed 55757(2352KB) AllocSpace objects, 150(23MB) LOS objects, 41% free, 34MB/58MB, paused 73us,54us total 153.175ms
2023-11-01 15:49:44.131  9559-9569  e.myproj.dem          com.myProject          I  Background concurrent copying GC freed 64824(2658KB) AllocSpace objects, 166(25MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 36MB/60MB, paused 66us,65us total 321.330ms
2023-11-01 15:49:45.102  9559-9569  e.myproj.dem          com.myProject          I  Background young concurrent copying GC freed 57539(2399KB) AllocSpace objects, 154(24MB) LOS objects, 40% free, 34MB/58MB, paused 64us,54us total 153.619ms
2023-11-01 15:49:45.591  9559-9565  e.myproj.dem          com.myProject          I  Thread[5,tid=9565,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb400007b28a286f0,peer=0x130c01f8,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
2023-11-01 15:49:45.591  9559-9565  e.myproj.dem          com.myProject          I  
2023-11-01 15:49:45.968  9559-9565  e.myproj.dem          com.myProject          I  Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
2023-11-01 15:49:46.267  9559-9569  e.myproj.dem          com.myProject          I  Background concurrent copying GC freed 65080(2672KB) AllocSpace objects, 169(26MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 36MB/60MB, paused 124us,57us total 335.014ms
2023-11-01 15:49:46.520  9559-9559  Thread-16               com.myProject          I  type=1400 audit(0.0:1906): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/dev/ttyS4" dev="tmpfs" ino=377 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c87,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:serial_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1 app=com.myProject
2023-11-01 15:49:47.279  9559-9569  e.myproj.dem          com.myProject          I  Background young concurrent copying GC freed 57588(2387KB) AllocSpace objects, 158(24MB) LOS objects, 41% free, 34MB/58MB, paused 67us,56us total 155.360ms
2023-11-01 15:49:47.473  9559-9559  Thread-16               com.myProject          I  type=1400 audit(0.0:1907): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/dev/ttyS4" dev="tmpfs" ino=377 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c87,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:serial_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=1 app=com.myProject
2023-11-01 15:49:47.549   606-19112 ActivityManager         system_process                       E  ANR in com.myProject
    PID: 9559
    Reason: executing service com.myProject/com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService
    ErrorId: bb96fcd1-1d47-4802-a819-6d869d90bfe3
    Frozen: false
    Load: 2.72 / 2.46 / 2.14
    ----- Output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
    some avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=24835
    full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=17016
    ----- End output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
    
    CPU usage from 19902ms to 0ms ago (2023-11-01 14:49:25.358 to 2023-11-01 14:49:45.260):
      103% 9559/com.myProject: 90% user + 13% kernel / faults: 379634 minor 9 major
      12% 408/android.hardware.camera.provider@2.4-external-service: 4.3% user + 8.1% kernel / faults: 40 minor
      9% 489/cameraserver: 5.6% user + 3.4% kernel / faults: 24 minor
      5.5% 329/surfaceflinger: 3.6% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 3 minor
      5.1% 481/adbd: 1.8% user + 3.3% kernel / faults: 19884 minor
      5% 354/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.1-service: 2.9% user + 2.1% kernel / faults: 24 minor
      2.6% 11981/kworker/u17:5-mali_kbase_csf_kcpu: 0% user + 2.6% kernel
      2.5% 5337/kworker/u17:4-kbase_pm_poweroff_wait: 0% user + 2.5% kernel
      2.1% 18865/kworker/u17:2-mali_kbase_csf_kcpu: 0% user + 2.1% kernel
      1.5% 1742/transport: 0.8% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 137 minor
      1.5% 14793/kworker/u17:3-mali_kbase_csf_kcpu: 0% user + 1.5% kernel
      1% 296/rknn_server: 0.2% user + 0.8% kernel
      0.9% 606/system_server: 0.6% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 908 minor
      0.8% 290/logd: 0.2% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 98 minor
      0.8% 7495/kworker/u16:2-devfreq_workq: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
      0.8% 12073/kworker/u16:1-events_unbound: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
      0.8% 15810/kworker/u16:4-events_unbound: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
      0.5% 144/queue_work1: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
      0.3% 1580/logcat: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel
      0.3% 12/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
      0.3% 162/irq/39-fdb90000: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
      0.3% 186/kworker/3:2-mm_percpu_wq: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
      0.3% 18548/kworker/0:1-pm: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
      0.3% 18909/kworker/1:1-events: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
      0.3% 20504/kworker/2:0-events: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
      0.2% 209/irq/36-rga3_cor: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
      0.2% 414/android.hardware.gnss@2.0-service: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel
      0.2% 1587/logcat: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel
      0.1% 13/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0.1% 17483/kworker/4:0H-events_highpri: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0% 8854/kworker/6:2H-events_highpri: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0.1% 15830/kworker/5:1H-events_highpri: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
      0% 18571/kworker/7:0H: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 263/kworker/1:2H: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 373/jbd2/mmcblk1p14: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 424/android.hardware.power-service.rockchip: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 5786/kworker/0:3H-mmc_complete: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 13078/kworker/7:2-events: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 18019/kworker/4:2-pm: 0% user + 0% kernel
      0% 18856/kworker/5:2-events: 0% user + 0% kernel
    22% TOTAL: 14% user + 5.8% kernel + 0% iowait + 1.1% irq + 0.9% softirq
    CPU usage from 12ms to 312ms later (2023-11-01 14:49:45.272 to 2023-11-01 14:49:45.572):
      58% 9559/com.myProject: 49% user + 8.9% kernel / faults: 4878 minor
        31% 10085/modelRunning: 31% user + 0% kernel
        4.4% 9559/e.myproj.demo: 0% user + 4.4% kernel
        4.4% 9597/RenderThread: 4.4% user + 0% kernel
        4.4% 9697/Binder:9559_5: 4.4% user + 0% kernel
        4.4% 10093/cameraRendering: 0% user + 4.4% kernel
        4.4% 11965/Thread-16: 0% user + 4.4% kernel
        4.4% 15090/Binder:9559_A: 0% user + 4.4% kernel
      19% 606/system_server: 7.7% user + 11% kernel / faults: 255 minor
        19% 19112/AnrConsumer: 7.7% user + 11% kernel
      7.2% 354/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.1-service: 7.2% user + 0% kernel
        3.6% 354/composer@2.1-se: 3.6% user + 0% kernel
      7.3% 408/android.hardware.camera.provider@2.4-external-service: 7.3% user + 0% kernel
        7.3% 11937/ExtCamOut: 3.6% user + 3.6% kernel
        3.6% 11952/ExtFmtCvt: 3.6% user + 0% kernel
```

When I removed the camera 2 feature, there was no problem